# Why are my cards not getting displayed at the center of the screen in android using Recyclerview and cardview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-cardview

So, I am trying to display the overlapped cards at the center of the screen but for some reason my cards are getting displayed without any marginTop like this shown in the image[image]

I want to display these cards closely above the two imageviews. i have created two xml layout files with one dedicated for cardview. This is my **to_learn_flashcards.xml** code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/new_design"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BACK"
        android:textColor="@color/new_design_text_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/back_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/back_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/back_icon"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/back_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/back_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/emptyImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageKeyboard"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/keyboard"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageSpeech"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/speech"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And below is my **recycle_view.xml** layout file which I have included in Recyclerview in above xml layout file .

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/experimental_color"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageCardHelper"
            android:src="@drawable/emoji" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/new_design_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/new_design_text_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I think one of the reasons might be using `layout_goneMarginTop` instead of regular marginTop. And another thing that I noticed is using marginHorizontal with marginStart and marginEnd, which of them is redundant. The same goes for your cardview as well. marginLeft and marginRight are unnecessary when using layout_margin.

Comment: Can you post the updated code?